# "Unable to locate session.php" message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project I am working on a button to send mail to client in codeigniter. When user click the button, following code is to be executed:

```
public function confirm()
{
    include_once("emailController.php");
    require_once('mailer/class.smtp.php');

    $pdfFile_info =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/email/resources/info/"."info.pdf";

    $subject="Info";
    $body="Please check the attached file(s).";

    $emailClient="client@gmail.com";

    $emailController =new emailController();

    $sendEmail=$emailController->sendEmail($subject,$body,$emailClient,$pdfFile_info);

    $this->load->view('confirm_msg');
}
```

Here `class.smtp.php` is of the library that I have used to send mail. And the first few lines of emailController() is given below (omitting the rest as they are not relevant here):

```
class emailController extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
            $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation','email'));
            $this->load->helper(array('html','form', 'url'));
            $this->load->driver('cache');
    }
      /*rest of the codes*/
}
```

The problem is when emailController is called from confirm() the browser shows the message "Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php", though session is loaded in emailController(). If I omit session from `$this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation','email'));` then it also shows the same message. What could be the problem here?

Comment: CI version?  If you're on CI 3.1.8 (latest) then your class name should be "EmailController" (capitalized first letter).  Probably not your issue, but something to think about.
Have you tried loading all the libraries needed through $autoload['libraries']?

Comment: use autoload.php to load all libraries and drivers

Comment: I have included $autoload['libraries'] = array('email','session'); in autoload.php but result is same.